# how to make multi dimension array from sql return rows in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

how to make multi dimension array from sql return rows in codeigniter.
return values from model holding all values in $res.

```
 $res = $this->user_model->get_room_book_join(['rooms.hotel_id' => 1]);
 if ($res) {
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($res);
 }
```

I getting this type of array.this type can not helping me.

```
    Array( [0] => Array
    (
        [room_id] => 1
        [room_no] => 101
        [room_desc] =>  Double Bed Deluxe Non Air Conditioned
        [status] => available
        [category_id] => 1
        [hotel_id] => 1
        [tariff_type] => normal
        [room_rate] => 1000
        [persons] => 0
        [date_start] => 0000-00-00
        [date_end] => 0000-00-00
        [overview_id] => 1
        [rom_id] => 1
        [hot_id] => 1
        [cus_id] => 2
        [bok_id] => 2
        [dates] => 2017-04-12
    )
   [1] => Array
    (
        [room_id] => 2
        [room_no] => 101
        [room_desc] =>  Double Bed Deluxe Non Air Conditioned
        [status] => available
        [category_id] => 1
        [hotel_id] => 1
        [tariff_type] => normal
        [room_rate] => 1000
        [persons] => 0
        [date_start] => 0000-00-00
        [date_end] => 0000-00-00
        [overview_id] => 1
        [rom_id] => 1
        [hot_id] => 1
        [cus_id] => 2
        [bok_id] => 2
        [dates] => 2017-04-13
    )
 )
```

Actually I want this type of array.how can i make it.please help advance thanks.

```
  array(
  [0]=>array(
   [room_id]=>1
   [dates]=>array(
    [0]=>2014-04-12
    [1]=>2014-04-13
    )
   )
  [1]=>array(
    [room_id]=>2
    [dates]=>array(
     [0]=>2014-04-12
     [1]=>2014-04-13
    )
   )
  )
```

Comment: You are already getting what you want. May be you need to re-do your query. Do you mind sharing your db schema and required results in tabular format.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi, you can try this code, this may help you**

$query = $this->db->get();

$result = $query->result_array();

$main_array=array();

$actual_array=array();

foreach($result as $res){

$main_array['room_id']=$res['room_id'];

$main_array['dates']=array($res['date_start'],$res['date_end']);

$actual_array[]=$main_array;

}

//echo ""; print_r($actual_array);

return $actual_array;

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 // after if ($res) {

for ($i=0; $i < count($res); $i++) { 
        $res[$i] = array(
            'room_id' => $res[$i]['room_id'],
            'dates' => array($res[$i]['date_start'],$res[$i]['date_end'])
        );
    }
```